# GATK g CNV code Aborts Before Running Main Code

Tags: gatk, cnv

I have been struggling to get the code I wrote for running GATK g CNV on my Linux machine (Steps Here: https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360035531152 ) to work. Specifically it seems to abort a run before running the main code (I even removed my DetermineGermlineContigPloidy step to no avail). Below is my code and then the error:

```sh
    
## Paths To Be Set

echo "My paths have been set"

### Set Bam Directory:
#### Make sure to set a seperate directory for the batch you are doing

BAM_DIR=/pathToThe/Batch_I_Am_Running

### Set the path to the reference genome:
reference=/pathToMy/primary_assembly.fa

#model_dir =/path/to/my/GATK-gCNV

### Set the path to the singularity image:
SINGULARITY_CACHEDIR=/path/to/my/GATK
singularity_image=$SINGULARITY_CACHEDIR/gatk_latest.sif

### Set Number Of Bins
#### Normally 100 to 200*

NUM_BINS=200

### Setting the number of threads ?? Like Cores ??

NUM_THREADS=20



#______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    
## Main code

echo "I am about to start the main code"

for c in "${CHROMOSOME_NAMES[@]}"; do

  # loop over the directories containing the BAM files
  for dir in "${BAM_DIR}"/*/; do

    # get the name of the directory without the path
    dir_name="$(basename "${dir}")"

    # get the name of the BAM file without the extension
    bam_name="$(basename "${dir}"/*.bam .bam)"

    echo "Processing file: $bam_name"

    echo "I am starting Step 1: Preprocessing"

    # Step 1: Preprocessing
    singularity exec $singularity_image PreprocessIntervals \
  -R ${reference} \
      -I ${dir}/${bam_name}.bam \
      -L targets.interval_list \
      --bin-length 0 \
      -imr OVERLAPPING_ONLY \
      -O targets.preprocessed.interval_list

    echo "I am starting Step 2: AnnotateIntervals with GC content"

    # Step 2: AnnotateIntervals with GC content
    singularity exec $singularity_image AnnotateIntervals \
  -L chr${c}.interval_list \
      -I ${dir}/${bam_name}.bam \
      -R ${reference} \
  -imr OVERLAPPING_ONLY \
  -O chr${c}.annotated.tsv

    echo "I am starting Step 3: CollectReadCounts"

    # Step 3: Collect read counts for the samples
    singularity exec $singularity_image CollectReadCounts \
  -I ${dir}/${bam_name}.bam \
  -L targets.preprocessed.interval_list \
  --interval-merging-rule OVERLAPPING_ONLY \
  --format TSV \
  -O ${dir_name}.${bam_name}.counts.tsv

    echo "I am starting Step 4: FilteringIntervals based on GC-content & read depth"

    # Step 4: FilterIntervals based on GC-content and read depth
    singularity exec $singularity_image FilterIntervals \
  -L chr${c}.interval_list \
      --annotated-intervals chr${c}.annotated.tsv \
  -imr OVERLAPPING_ONLY \
  "${dir}"/*.counts.tsv \
      --max-panel-norm 1.5 \
      --min-panel-norm 0.3 \
      -O chr${c}.filtered.interval_list

    echo "Not doing Step 5 DetermineGermlineContigPloidy for now"

    # Step 5: DetermineGermlineContigPloidy (Mandatory Step)
   # singularity exec $singularity_image DetermineGermlineContigPloidy \
 # --model-parameters ${model_dir}/model_parameters.txt \
     # --contig-ploidy-calls ${model_dir}/contig_ploidy_calls.tsv \
 # --contig-ploidy-priors chr20XY_contig_ploidy_priors.tsv \
 # --output-prefix ${model_dir}/ploidy \
     # --standardized-output \
     # $(find "${output_dir}" -name "*.calls.tsv" -printf '%p ') \

#    for file in ${input_dir}/*.tsv
#    do

    # Get sample ID from filename
#      sample=$(basename ${file} .tsv)
#      # Run DetermineGermlineContigPloidy command
#      singularity exec ${singularity_image} DetermineGermlineContigPloidy \
#        --input ${file} \
#        --contig-ploidy-priors ${contig_ploidy_priors} \
#        --output-prefix ${output_dir}/${sample}_ploidy \
#        --standardized-output
#    done

    echo "Creating shards via bins"

    # Creating shards via bins
    singularity exec $singularity_image IntervalListTools \
  SplitIntervals \
  -R ${reference} \
      -L chr${c}.interval_list \
  -scatter ${NUM_BINS} \
      -o ${dir}/${c}_shard.interval_list

    echo "Starting the Shard Loop that will run GermlineCNVCaller and PostprocessGermlineCNVCalls"

    # Loop over the shards and run GermlineCNVCaller and PostprocessGermlineCNVCalls
    for shard_file in "${dir}/${c}"*_shard.interval_list; do

      echo "Starting Step 6: Run GermlineCNVCaller (Mandatory Step)"

      # Step 6: Run GermlineCNVCaller (Mandatory Step)
      singularity exec $singularity_image GermlineCNVCaller \
    --run-mode COHORT \
    -L "${shard_file}" \
        -I $(find "${dir}" -name "*.tsv" -printf '%p ') \
        --minimum-interval-median-percentile 5.0 \
        --maximum-zeros-in-sample-percentage 40.0 \
        --annotation-cutoffs "QD=2.0" "SOR=2.0" "FS=10.0" "MQ=50.0" \
        --interval-merging-rule OVERLAPPING_ONLY \
        --output-prefix $(basename "${shard_file}" .interval_list)

      echo "Starting Step 7: Run PostprocessGermlineCNVCalls (Mandatory Step)"

      # Step 7: Run PostprocessGermlineCNVCalls (Mandatory Step)
      singularity exec $singularity_image PostprocessGermlineCNVCalls \
    --model-shard-path "${shard_file}" \
        --cnv-call-path $(basename "${shard_file}" .interval_list).calls.tsv \
        --output-dir postprocess-sm \
        --scatter-count ${NUM_THREADS} \
        --num-scatter-plot-columns 8 \
        --max-zeros-in-sample-percentage 40.0 \
        --annotation-cutoffs "QD=2.0" "SOR=2.0" "FS=10.0" "MQ=50.0" \
        --interval-merging-rule OVERLAPPING_ONLY \
        --minimum-contig-length 46709983 \
        --minimum-interval-median-percentile 5.0

    done


  done


done

    #______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

The ".out" file I received after the run aborted is:

> My paths have been set
>
> I am about to start the main code

Why would it abort so soon (I changed the number of Gs used and that did not have any effect)?

Comment: Please don't dump 168 lines of code on us and expect us to debug it. You need to make this more focused: give us a _minimal_ script that still produces the error. You haven't even put in the minimal effort to remove commented lines of code here! In this case, the error is trivial, but as a general rule, you need to help us help you.

Comment: I will try. I am still getting used to coding. Shouldn't commented lines remain?

Comment: No worries, we all start somewhere! Just remember the first rule of debugging: ***print all the things***! By far the most common source of bugs is that the developer assumes their variables have one value, but actually the variables have another value. So the first step, _always_, should be to print out the variables, and to add simple print statements like `echo "I got to here!"` at different places in your code so you can figure out exactly where the problem occurs.

Comment: That is what I was trying to do with the `echo` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `${CHROMOSOME_NAMES[@]}` but you never define that, so when your code gets here:

```
for c in "${CHROMOSOME_NAMES[@]}"; do
...
done
```

It doesn't enter the `for` loop because `"${CHROMOSOME_NAMES[@]}"` is an empty array. It's the same thing as doing this in a shell session:

```
$ for c in "${CHROMOSOME_NAMES[@]}"; do echo "This is chromosome $c"; done
$
```

Just like your script, that will produce no output since there is nothing for it to loop over.

Comment: Thank you for this I will try it out seems that I removed my code `CHROMOSOME_NAMES=( $(seq 1 22) X Y)`